# Prevent Android from Killing Paused Audio Service

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer

As of Android API 26, the Android system requires that a Service that ["performs some operation that is noticeable to the user"](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) register itself as a foreground service. And "foreground services must display a Notification."

I have a Service that plays audio files. When playback is paused, the user should be able to swipe the notification away (as with the Google Play Music app). But if I call `stopForeground()` then my Service is killed by the system within a few minutes.

How can I allow the notification to be swiped away when playback is paused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But if I call stopForeground() then my Service is killed by the system within a few minutes

On Android 8.0+, it will be stopped after a minute.

> How can I allow the notification to be swiped away when playback is paused?

Step #0: Save any data that you really need (e.g., track and playback position) to disk

Step #1: Call `stopForeground()`

Step #2: Raise a fresh notification, one without the "ongoing" flag set (i.e., `setOngoing(false)`, which is the default), to reflect your paused state

Step #3: Ideally, call `stopSelf()`, to get the service out of memory and reduce your process importance to a normal level, rather than waiting the minute for Android to stop your service